# How to pass a value into a string in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it even possible to pass a value in ggplot?

It is possible in a console using `cat`

```
v <- 8
ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Fold_Change, color = Category)) +
labs(y= "RNA expression", x = cat("p-value = 0.08831", v) )
```

but what about graph?

Comment: `cat` says 'print to console'. Try using `paste()` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sprintf instead of cat, for example:

```
x = sprintf("%s %f %d", "p-value = ", 0.08831, v) )
```

I don't see any *geom* phrase in your example. I put some bogus data into a data.frame and used geom_point() to produce a plot for this example.

```
v <- 8
ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Fold_Change, color = Category)) +
geom_point() + 
labs(y= "RNA expression", x = sprintf("%s %f %d", "p-value = ", 0.08831, v) )
```

[image: example plot using sprintf]